# Get child of terms from WP_Term_Query

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to WordPress and like to get all the terms which are the **children** of term_id = 1,

Below is my code snippet of Term Query, and in the screenshot shows the category structure.

But what i got from the log, it will show all of terms. I tried 'parent' as well, but not work.

(Version WordPress 6.0)

```
$term_args = [
    'taxonomy'              => 'category',
    'hide_empty'            => 0,
    'hierarchical'          => 1,
    'child_of'              => 1
];

$terms = new \WP_Term_Query($term_args);
if (!is_admin()){
    var_dump($terms->get_terms());
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8g3Pf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) for that. Below code gets all child terms for a parent.

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy'              => 'category',
    'hide_empty'            => 0,
    'hierarchical'          => 1,
    'child_of'              => 1
);

$taxonomies = get_terms( $args );
if ( !empty( $taxonomies ) || !is_wp_error( $taxonomies ) ) {
    var_dump($taxonomies);
}
```

It works on my end!